# Ruby on Rails 3 howto make 'OR' condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need an SQL statement that check if one condition is satisfied:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.x=1 OR my_table.y=1
```

I want to do this the 'Rails 3' way. I was looking for something like:

```
Account.where(:id => 1).or.where(:id => 2)
```

I know that I can always fallback to sql or a conditions string. However, in my experience this often leads to chaos when combining scopes. What is the best way to do this?

Another related question, is how can describe relationship that depends on an OR condition. The only way I found:

```
has_many :my_thing, :class_name => "MyTable",  :finder_sql => 'SELECT my_tables.* ' + 'FROM my_tables ' +
'WHERE my_tables.payer_id = #{id} OR my_tables.payee_id = #{id}'
```

However, these again breaks when used in combinations. IS there a better way to specify this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly, the .or isn't implemented yet (but when it is, it'll be AWESOME).

So you'll have to do something like:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sufficient_data, :conditions=>['ratio_story_completion != 0 OR ratio_differential != 0']
  scope :profitable, :conditions=>['profit > 0']
```

That way you can still be awesome and do:

```
Project.sufficient_data.profitable
```

Comment: from the arel github site:

   The OR operator is not yet supported. It will work like this:

   users.where(users[:name].eq('bob').or(users[:age].lt(25)))

Answer (score 113):

`Account.where(id: [1,2])` no explanation needed.

Comment: The cleanest, DRYest one I've seen. Good Job!

Comment: This is great, and so simple. I've also learned that you can use `nil` safely: e.g. `Thing.where(foo: [1, nil])` will get translated to `SELECT "things".* FROM "things" WHERE (("things"."foo" = 1 OR "things"."foo" IS NULL))`. Brilliant!

Comment: But for example if you use "A is not null OR A is null" you can't use this answer, but nevertheless you can use `Account.arel_table[:id].not_eq(nil)` and `.or()` combinations in rails 3

Comment: Loving this solution. Every other answer out there is so needlessly complex!

Comment: This is an answer to a different question.  The original question asks `my_table.x=1 OR my_table.y=1` x and y are different columns in the table

Comment: This works for only one field.

Answer (score 76):

This will works in Rails 5, see [rails master](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9e42cf019f2417473e7dcbfcb885709fa2709f89) :

```
Post.where('id = 1').or(Post.where('id = 2'))
# => SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (id = 1) OR (id = 2)
```

For Rails 3.0.4+:

```
accounts = Account.arel_table
Account.where(accounts[:id].eq(1).or(accounts[:id].eq(2)))
```

Comment: Definitely dislike this syntax. Still, though, interesting.

Comment: I like it because it can be combinatory

Answer (score 16):

Those arel queries are unreadable to me.

What's wrong with a SQL string? In fact, the Rails guides exposes this way as the first way to make conditions in queries: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions

So, I bet for this way to do it as the "Rails way":

```
Account.where("id = 1 OR id = 2")
```

In my humble opinion, it's shorter and clearer.

Comment: Prefer this, but I would use parameterized values. `Account.where("id = ? OR id = ?",1,2)`

Comment: I don't see any reason for parameterized values when using simple numbers.

Comment: If you are hardcoding the id then no simple numbers would be fine but I would suspect these are being returned from elsewhere so paramterised is the way to go to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Sure, as the first commenter states, using parameters is the good way to do it. I just wrote hardcoded numbers as an example.

Answer (score 6):

I'd go with the `IN` clause, e.g:

```
Account.where(["id in (?)", [1, 2]])
```

Comment: That would be appropriate, but notice the author is looking @ 2 different fields...

Comment: Oh yes that's true, I wrote the answer based in this statement `Account.where(:id => 1).or.where(:id => 2)`. Obviously It doesn't work for different fields.

Comment: Won't work if one of the value in array is `nil`. Say you want to find all records where "viewed" is either `false` or `nil` and you do `Notification.where(:viewed => [false, nil])`, it won't work, as MySQL requires the syntax `viewed = 0 OR viewed IS NULL` and *won't work with* `viewed = 0 OR viewed = NULL` or `viewed IN (0, NULL)`.

Comment: `Account.where(["id in (?)", [1, 2]])` you forgot the `(  ?  )`

Answer (score 5):

I've used the Squeel gem (https://github.com/ernie/squeel/) to do OR queries and it works beautifully.

It lets you write your query as `Account.where{(id == 1) | (id == 2)}`

Answer (score 4):

You can define an Array as value in the `:conditions` Hash.

So you could do for example:

```
Account.all(:conditions => { :id => [1, 2] })
```

Tested with Rails 3.1.0

Comment: this is inefficient because you are retrieving all items from database and checking in memory

Answer (score 2):

Alternate syntax using Hash

```
Account.where("id = :val1 OR id = :val2", val1: 1, val2: 2).
```

This is particularly useful, when the value is compared with multiple columns. eg:

```
User.where("first_name = :name OR last_name = :name", name: 'tom')
```

Answer (score 1):

With [rails_or](https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or), you could do it like:

```
Account.where(id: 1).or(id: 2)
```

(It works in Rails 4 and 5, too.)