# What is the "Rails Way" of doing a query with an OR clause using ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3 with a MySQL database, and I need to programmatically create a query like this:

```
select * from table where category_name like '%category_name_1%' 
OR category_name like '%category_name_2%'
(...snip...)
OR category_name like '%category_name_n%'
```

Given the table size and the project scope (500 rows at most, I think), I feel that using something like thinking sphinx would be overkill. 
I know I could simply do this by writing the query string directly, but wanted to know if there's an ActiveRecord way to do this. There's no mention of this on the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), and I've been googling for a long while now, just to end empty-handed :(

Also, is there a reason (maybe a Rails reason?) to not to include the OR clause?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there is no mention in the guide you sited.  Section 2.2 contains a very similar example (with 'and' instead of 'or' and '=' instead of 'like').

Comment: That's right, but please take a look at my reply to your comment below...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have an array `names` with category names:

```
Model.where( names.map{"category_name LIKE ?"}.join(" OR "),
  *names.map{|n| "%#{n}%" } )
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. just a little modification to your example: `Model.where(names.map{"category_name LIKE ?"}.join(" OR "), *names.map{|n|"%#{n}%"})`... the #{ } around "n" was missing

Answer (score 4):

you should google first, there is already an answer.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291152/ruby-on-rails-3-howto-make-or-condition) and then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails-3)
and you'll get something like this:

```
accounts = Account.arel_table
Account.where(accounts[:name].matches("%#{user_name}%").or(accounts[:name].matches("%#{user_name2}%")))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the guide, they have examples that can easily be modified to this:

```
Client.where("orders_count = ? OR locked = ?", params[:orders], false)
```

Comment: What if you want to add another OR clause to the query after certain condition? For example, in addition to orders_count and locked, you want to add something like `OR id_number = ?`

Comment: Client.where("orders_count = ? OR locked = ? OR id_number = ?", params[:orders], false, id) (?????)

Comment: What I meant was  how to programmatically add the third (or fourth) OR , not just altering the query string...

Comment: Ah, in that case you would want to use `.or`

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has a regexp function now that can clean things up a bit, assuming there's no regex metachars in your category names:

```
Table.where "category_name regexp '#{names.join('|')}'"
```