# Safe querying by find, sql, or where

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to find all widgets with their common or internal names in a certain list `query_list`. I can do

```
# Consider query_list = ["a","b","c"]
qlist = '(' + query_list.join(",") + ')'
# this makes 
widgets = Widget.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM widgets 
     WHERE common_name IN #{qlist} OR internal_name IN #{qlist}")
```

Now I have a few questions:

1. Is the above find_by_sql safe regarding SQL injection attacks? It seems like one could put in something dangerous in `query_list`.

   - How about writing `.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM widgets
          WHERE common_name IN ? OR internal_name IN ?", ["a","b","c"], ["a","b","c"] ])`
   - If it isn't safe, can we make it safe?
2. I prefer not to write raw sql if I don't have to. I know we can write `AND` conditions in `find`, as in `.find(:conditions=>{:internal_name => ['a','b','c'], :common_name => ['a','b','c']})`. Can we also write `OR` conditions using find?
3. How about using `where`? How is this different from using `find`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version with placeholders is safe against SQL injection, as long as you don't mind users being able to select arbitrary widgets, which I assume you don't.  Depending on what version of Rails you have, you can avoid writing raw SQL using chaining; see [Ruby on Rails 3 howto make 'OR' condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291152/ruby-on-rails-3-howto-make-or-condition).

Note that your code as is, or with the placeholders, will cause a database error if the list is empty, or is `[nil]`, so it's best to test that query_list.first is present before making the query.